# Trouble with typing $\sec^2$ into a calculator

Tags: calculator

$\frac{1}{4} (\frac{1}{4} \sec^2(\frac{1}{4}) + 2\tan(\frac{1}{4})) $

How do I input $\sec^2 $ onto the calculator ?

Comment: $1/cos^2(1/4) $

Comment: $ (1 \div \cos( 1 \div 4 ) )^2$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$ and $$\sec(x)^2=\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}$$
and in your case $$\left(\sec(1/4)\right)^2=\frac{1}{(\cos(1/4))^2}$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/822036)

Comment: can you tell me why? i know this phrase

Comment: @TheCount: That is _often_ a relevant critique to level at Sonnhard's answers, but it's a mystery to me how you think it applies _here_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It doesn't at all help the poster get the requested thing into the calculator, it merely restates the rules for the trig functions. If you disagree, that's ok.

Comment: @TheCount: Are you seeing the same question as I see? This answer tells the OP _exactly_ how he gets a calculator with standard keys to compute a secant for him -- which is what was asked.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes I see the same question. I think this is a low-quality answer. If you disagree, that's fine. I'm not interested in arguing about it or being condescended to.

Comment: @TheCount: What do you _possibly_ think would be a better answer? You're being needlessly condescending towards a perfectly good, correct and complete answer; if you cannot take being called out on it, _you_ are the one with the power to improve your behavoir.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Describing how to do it *on a calculator*.

Comment: @TheCount: Are you thinking the answer should have explained where on the asker's calculator the cosine key is located? The asker did not even explain which model of calculator he's using!

Comment: yeah the Picture of the calculator was deleted!

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not saying you are wrong. I'm saying I disagree with your assesment of the answer. I hope that is okay with you.